# why pipeline run only first gitlab-runner?

Tags: gitlab

I register 6 gitlab-runner then when push to gitlab server, pipline only run first gitlab-runner? why is this happening?
I expect the pipeline to run on 6 servers.
thanx.

Comment: Are the jobs in the pipeline marked for parallel execution?

Comment: Show all applicable code and configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

This is well-known behaviour on ssh services, but as your tools implementation is not described in detail I have no idea whether this is a similar issue.

With ssh, the problem is that the local service assumes that the remote service will read stdin from the local machine. So it pre-emptively reads local data, and sends a block to the remote to inprove its start-up time.

If you are in a loop of remote calls, that sucks all the input out of the loop control and the second loop cycle gets EOF.

The fix in ssh is (a) to use a -n option to inhibit the sending of local data, or (b) redirecting the ssh input from /dev/null so it can't read anyway.

You could also put data into the ssh command itself as an echo, or pipe its input from a file or another local command, thereby bypassing the local stdin.

You should be able to execute your git-lab-runner under strace to discover whether it is reading stdin unexpectedly.